# Is there any way to link two different pipelines using jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Developer team needs a pipeline should only be allowed to start only if another related pipeline has completed and they need the pipeline view on same page

It is something like this , a set of stages complete and the next stages would start when project manager starts the pipeline manually .

Simply they need to visualize both pipelines in a single page like below picture.

(https://puppet.com/sites/default/files/2016-09/puppet_continuous_diagram.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the step `build job: '<first_pipeline>', parameters: [...]` in say, stage 1 of your second pipeline as a upstream job. Then define the steps of your second pipeline from stage 2 onwards. This will make sure that the first pipeline is always built when you trigger the second and also works with delivery pipeline view for single page visualization.

Or, if you just want to check if the first pipeline is completed without actually triggering it, use the api `<jenkins_url>/job/<first_pipeline>/lastBuild/api/json` in stage 1 of your second pipeline with a while loop to wait until the status is “completed”.

Comment: This looks promising, Thanks Dibakar for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of a way to link them, but you could write the steps in the same pipeline.

You can work with [input](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) steps to ask for the project manager to confirm. Note that this halts an entire build processor until confirmed (or you set a timeout).

You might also want to have a look at [conditional](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/) steps.

Comment: Thanks smelm,I have tried both the options you have mentioned. But I need the second pipeline to run manually as well, As a workaround for now I am using Delivery Pipeline View , which comes with the pipeline plugin I guess.

Comment: I think Dibakar answered what I needed, Thanks again smelm for the suggestions.